# How to interpret this summation from an IMO question.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation

[image]

This is extracted from a question in IMO. Can someone explain this summation for the case $k=1$. I don't understand when $k=1$, how the term $(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{k-1})^2$ will be expressed because there shouldn't have defined $a_0$, so how is this summation make sense when $k=1$?

Comment: The usual convention is that $a_1+a_2+\cdots+ a_t=0$ for $t=0$ (i.e. you can read it as $\sum_{1\le m\le t}a_m$ ).

Comment: I believe for purity lower index in outer sum should be $k=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Given a commutative monoid $(M, +, 0)$, and $I$ and $J$ disjoint nonempty finite subsets of a set $E$ of indices, one has
$$
\sum_{i \in I}x_i + \sum_{i \in J} x_i = \sum_{i \in I \cup J} x_i
$$
In order to extend this formula to the case where $I$ or $J$ are empty, you need to assume that $\sum_{i \in \emptyset}x_i = 0$. This is one of the reasons why this convention is used in mathematics. Thus in your case, the term corresponding to $k = 1$ is $0$.